# How to make serial reading asynchronously to main loop

Tags: arduino

I have arduino with code below. It has encoder, and prints something on encoder turn. But also it receive a lot of data, so if arduino is reading serial main loop stops and encoder loosing steps. How can I write code where encoders printing has always priority?

code:

```
#include <Encoder.h>

String receivedData = "";
Encoder encoder1(24, 25);
long position1  = -999;
long newPosition1;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(57600);
}

void loop() {

  newPosition1 = encoder1.read();
  if (newPosition1 != position1) {
    Serial.print("PrintSomething");
  }
  position1 = newPosition1;

  Serial.flush();
  if(Serial.available() > 0) {
    receivedData = Serial.readStringUntil(';');
    if (receivedData == "?") {
      Serial.print("3," + String(deviceId) + ",0,0,3;");
    }
    doSomethingImmediatly();
  }
}
```

Important thing is in reality i have 6 encoders, so i can't use interrupts. And doSomethingImmediatly function should run as fast as possible.

Funny thing is if i use higher braud the problem is even more visible.

Answer (score 1):

1. I would strongly suggest using `SerialEvent` instead of polling for serial data. This way, you build the serial string char by char and you can decide where to stop reading.
2. I would rather poll the encoders to avoid using clock cycles reading the status of every encoder sequentially. Otherwise, reconsider using a different library that might offer better performance (like [RotaryEncoder](https://github.com/mathertel/RotaryEncoder) from mathertel)
3. Based on the number of encoders that you are trying to read and the potential bottlenecks that you will encounter at 16 MHz (most common clock speed from Arduino - unless us Due or Mega-), I advise porting your application to a Teensy Microcontroller (> 3.2)

Keep in mind, there is no such thing as 'priorities' unless, as lurker mentioned, you use RTOS. You have to play with timings and efficient logic

For instance, a skimmed example code would look like the following (it shows only one polling routine):

```
unsigned long previousEncoderTime;
unsigned long pollPeriod = 200;    // Poll every 200 ms
char serialString[] = "    "; // Empty serial string variable
bool stringFinished = false; // Flag to indicate reception of a string after terminator is reached

void setup(){
    previousEncoderTime = 0;

}

void loop(){

    unsigned long now = millis();

    if (now - previousEncoderTime >= pollPeriod){
        previousEncoderTime  = now;
        // Encoder reading routine
    } 

    if (stringFinished){ // When the serial Port has received a command

        stringFinished = false;
       // Implement your logic here

    }

}

void serialEvent()
{
    int idx = 0;

    while (Serial.available())
    {
        char inChar = (char)Serial.read();

        if (inChar == '\n')    // The reading event stops at a new line character
        {
            serialTail = true;
            serialString[idx] = inChar;
        }

        if (!serialTail)
        {
            serialString[idx] = inChar;
            idx++;
        }

        if (serialTail)
        {
            stringFinished = true;
            Serial.flush();
            serialTail = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Today i found time to test it. Unfortunately your solution doesn't work for me, but in thanks to you i found the solution, so.. Thanks ;).

Approach with serialEvent() and this line do the job:
   char inChar = (char)Serial.read();

Comment: Glad to know that I could be of help. Cheers